# How to execute and query in VBA in MS Access using the ODBC Connector for MySQl?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access, odbc, mysql-odbc-connector

The following VBA code will allow you to run a sql query in the current access database

I tried this in a MS Access file that is connected to a MySQL database through the ODBC Connector. However this code does not work, presumably because it's not a normal access DB.

How can I query the database using the existing ODBC connection?

EDIT: I always get a "Runtime error 3024 cannot find file"

Try 1

```
Dim mydb As Database
Dim myrs As DAO.Recordset


Set mydb = CurrentDb

Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset("select from blah blah...")
```

---

Try 2

```
Dim dbMine As DAO.Database
Set dbMine = CurrentDb

Dim qr As String
qr = "select count(*) as `result` from floatinp_appdb2.clientes where cliente_email = 'tiagovalente@float-in.pt';"
'debug.print qr
dbMine.Execute qr, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: what does "However, this code does not work....." mean? Are you getting an error? if so, what does it say? Is nothing happening at all? Does it do something but just not what you expect it to do? Please provide as much information as possible about what is happening.

Comment: Error 3024 Couldn't find file!

Comment: what file does it say it can't fine? you might want to take a look at this: https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/microsoft/microsoft-access/error-3024_microsoft-access-error-3024#:~:text=Runtime%20Error%203024%20happens%20when,work%20during%20its%20run%2Dtime.

Comment: it can't find itself

Comment: I just linked an article from ErrorVault.com in my previous comment that talks about your error and possible ways to fix it. Take a look and see if any of the solutions help you out, and if they do please post the answer here for the benefit of others that have the same error.

Comment: thanks but, the article has nothing to do with the question. the problem is that I want to reference the ODBC Connector

Comment: You can't query the connector, you can query a linked table. Please show your actual code.

Comment: @Andre I'm trying but I always get a "runtime error 3024 cannot find file"

Answer (score 0):

Requirements  are:
Linked table has a PK defined.

So, this should work:

```
Set myrs = mydb.OpenRecordset("select from blah blah...",dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Also:
any true/false columns (bit fields) should have default value of 0 set. (don't allow nulls for the true/false columns).

You can and should also consider adding a rowversion column, but above should suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still get a "runtime error 3024 cannot find file"

Comment: Can you open the linked table from the Access UI? can you edit a record by opening the linked table? Flip the linked table into design view (yes to read only prompt). Now, does the table designer show a PK set? Also, try pasting your query into the query builder? Your as clause does not need quotes around the aliased column name. So get the query working FIRST in the access query builder (flip to sql  view - paste in your sql query - does it work?

Comment: I do have PK set, but my query came was written in MySQL and included the name of the database before the table e.g. db2.table1 thank you for the help

Comment: Well, you have to use the same name as what you have for linked tables, or you can re-name the linked tables to have  the same name as the MySQL  tables. Of course re-naming tables  if you built code, forms, and reports based on the existing name would be a bad idea. You can adopt a pass-though query and that will allow you to paste in raw 100% MySQL format into a access query. This includes db prefix, and the name of linked tables will not matter. So you can if you want use a pass-through query and you thus use 100% MySQL syntax. You don't even require to have the table linked local.

Answer (score 0):

Though the error was "runtime error 3024 cannot find file", my mistake was including the database name before the table

e.g. Select * From DB2.Table1